# Customizing moreNavigationController in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

i know there are already some threads to this topic but they only solved my problem partly.
I managed to customize the moreNavigationController navigationBar color and the label color see here:
[image: picture1]

But i got some problems by customizing the view which shows if you click on "edit" on the right side. This is how it looks at the moment:
[image: picture2]

What do i want to achieve ?

- color the done in white
- color the navigationBar in red
- color the icon tint in red

I already got a reference to my UITabbarController in my AppDelegate via

```
 UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
```

And i also set the delegate of this tabBarController and the delegate method `- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController willBeginCustomizingViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers` also gets called. But from there i can't color these three controls. Somebody got a hint for me ?

For example this:

```
id modalViewCtrl = [[[tabBarController view] subviews] objectAtIndex:1];
if([modalViewCtrl isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITabBarCustomizeView")] == YES)
    ((UINavigationBar*)[[modalViewCtrl subviews] objectAtIndex:0]).barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

and also this:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)controller willBeginCustomizingViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers {
UIView *editView = [controller.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
UINavigationBar *modalNavBar = [editView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
modalNavBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

}

does just nothing or crashes for barTintColor, because it "can't set barTintColor on UILabel" . But i'm not quite sure how to retrieve the different controls to set their color values..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. I should have logged `edit_views` then i would have seen, that the `navigationBar` is at index 1 and not 0. Then on index 2-end there are the `UITabBarButtons` where i cant set the right color..

The final code looks like this:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
     willBeginCustomizingViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers
{
    UIView*          edit_views = [tabBarController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
    UINavigationBar* bar        = [[edit_views subviews]objectAtIndex:1];

    bar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    bar.tintColor    = [UIColor whiteColor];
    for (int i = 3; i < [edit_views.subviews count]; i++)
    {
        UIButton *button = [[edit_views subviews]objectAtIndex:i];
        button.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this effect without messing around with the UIView hierarchy by using UIAppearance and setting the `tintColor` of your window. Therefore you could place this code in your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
[self.window setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

You could also restrict the UIAppearance code by using `appearanceWhenContainedIn:` if you want different styling of your navigation bar in different view controllers.